# javascript: multiple classes "stored" within an object?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, javascript-objects

I have a feeling that there is something terrebly wrong with the way ive stacked multiple classes in the example below:
(ps. this example is only to show the pattern im refering to)

```
const itemClasses = {
    ItemOne: class {
            constructor (somethings) {
                        this.thatThing = somethings;
                    }
            doThing() {
                        /*some code*/
                    }
            },
    ItemTwo: class {
            constructor (somethings) {
                        this.thatThing = somethings;
                    }
            doThing() {
                        /*Do another thing!*/
                    }
            }
}
```

I ask the question since while trying to learn the basics i only find examples of classes beeing defined globally with "class XX()"

I find it neat to gather classes in objects for two reasons.

1. Keeps the namespace cleaner when using many smaller classes.
2. You can programmatically pick different classes easier: Like:

```
    new entity[variable](param)
```

Does it take cost resources (ram/cpu) to put classes within "parent objects" or are there any other reason not to stack classes like this.

If there are no issues, would it be fine to go one step further and nest like this:

```
 const classes = {
    items = {
        /*Classes in here*/
    },
    entities = {
        /*Classes in here*/
    }
}
```

ps. Ive gotten the great tip of using [ES module syntax]. Im yet to understand module syntax gives mostly readability benefits or if there are other substantial gains as well, looking into it =D
Thanks for your answers so far.

Comment: It is. Make your classes normal class declarations, and then you can trivially aggregate them if you want, but the ES module syntax _already_ lets you do this in an _even nicer_ way than what you're showing. Export both classes from one file, then import them in whatever needs them as `import { Item, Enemy } from "./my-game-classes.js";` And then if you _really_ want you can declare `const entities = { Item, Enemy };` so you can blind-construct them, but good code should not need that: it should be pretty clean when something's an item vs. when it's an enemy, with explicit constructors.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your fast answer @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans ! <3 You are a hero for lending me some of your time =D
Even as a beginner I understand that it should be a clear difference between like, an item and enemy =D  baaad example =S
In actual use im looking at different types of basicly the same thingisch.  with quite few differences in a few prototype methods. (drawing on canvas things)
Thats besides the point thou =D
I had a feeling that i was missing something big conceptually. Could you explain/link why normal class declarations are better/whats the difference (besides readabillity)

Comment: Then I would strongly recommend spending a bit of time on [improving your post](/help/how-to-ask) so that you can show a well crafted, close-to-real-world example that illustrates what you're doing. People are going to nitpick the code you show, so make sure they're not nitpicking the wrong parts =)

Comment: Yeah, i should have spent more time when making up the example.
Or at the very least been more clear what i was after.
TBH i dont really have a real world example to base my question on, im just trying to understand different ways to write/initiate objects and work with prototypes.
Ill read the link and make sure i make a bettre formulation next time (if i dare to ever try again hehe).
Thanks once again @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans for lending me some time!
Ill have a look at ES module syntax to understand why its bettre.

Comment: hint _hint_ **_hint_**: the edit button is right there, don't just say "I should have", actually do and then [update your post](/help/how-to-ask). The process doesn't stop now that you've posted: you are still in the driving seat, and you should still make sure your post gets updated to best reflect your problem, even _after_ the initial submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it take alot more memory, or is it slower?

No, it's a totally fine pattern. Namespaces do help with code organisation, although they feel a bit dated - ES6 modules are the way to go.

> Are there any other reason not to do this?

The example you gave

```
new entity[variable]("xx", "yy")
```

is broken. This works only if all your classes have the same constructor signature, but in your example `ItemOne` takes a color and a size whereas `ItemTwo` takes a type and a value. Passing `"yy"` as a value doesn't work since `ItemOne` expects a number as the size.

Maybe that's only because of the quickly sketched example, but keep this in mind. Of course, there are still cases where you need to resolve classes by name even if the parameter types don't match, but you'll need to ensure that the arguments fit.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @Bergi
Yeah my quickly sketched example really did bite my in my *ss it seems.
Im terrebly sorry for makeing the issue harder to understand!
I dont have a real world project to base it off, just trying to get my head around classes, constructor functions, factoryfunctions, prototypes etc etc.. its a alot to take in hehe =D

Ill have a look at ES6 modules and try to figure out why its the bettre option for mutiple classes!
Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: @HappyImbecile No, it's not "*the better option for multiple classes*", it's the better option for anything you might want to put into a namespace object

Comment: Aaah ok :) thanks again!